# php is not creating unique session

Tags: php, session, model-view-controller, authentication

I am having a problem with my mvc framework, my entire site is using a single session id so when I log in using my pc as soon as i visit the site with another device that device uses that same session , Does anyone know where the problem might be  this is the code inside my `sessions.php` file where sessions are set

```
public static function set($value,$key)
{    
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

And below is my login function

```
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   $password = md5($password);
   $statement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email AND password=:password");
   $statement->execute(array(':email'=>$email,':password'=>$password));

   $results = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $count = $statement->rowCount();

   if ($count>0) {
       $id = $results['id'];
       session::init();
       session::set($id,"id");

       echo json_encode(array('status'=>true));
   }
```

Comment: Not an answer, but using md5 for password storage is very weak. Have a look at password_hash()! Also I think the relevant part of the code is in session::init().

Comment: `session id` where ?

Answer (score 0):

You have...

```
session::set($id,"id");
```

And your function, once more..

```
public static function set($value,$key)
{    
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
}
```

You're setting the key of "id" to whatever the "id" is of the record in the database.  There's no reason for this value to change, unless you change it in the database.